# How to fix "trim" not working in mongoose schemas

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm learning mongoose and tried setting "trim" to true inside a mongoose schema. However it is not working as expected.

I've tried setting other things like "lowercase" to true and it does work, so I don't know why "trim" isn't working.

```
var userSchema = {
    name: {type: String, required: true, trim: true, lowercase: true},
    email: {
        type: String, 
        required: true,
        validate: function(value){
            if(!(validator.isEmail(value))){
                throw new Error("Not a valid email address");
            }
        },
        trim: true,
    },
    age: {
        type: Number,
        validate: function(value){
            if(value < 0){
                throw new Error("Age must be a positive number");
            }
        },
        default: 0
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 7,
        validate: function(value){
            if(value.toLowerCase().includes("password")){
                throw new Error(" Passwords should not contain the word 
'password ' ");
            }
        },
        trim: true
    }
}

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

var someuser = new User({
    name: "some user",
    age: 25,
    email: "user@something.com",
    password: "verysecurepassword"
})
```

I expected an the name of the new user to be 'someuser', but instead it turned out to be 'some user'.

Comment: 'trim' property only removes whitespaces from the start and end of a string, not from the middle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name "some user" has space in the middle of the string.

What you are trying to do will not work as `trim` will remove whitespaces from start and end of string only.

Answer (score 0):

Please check `trim()` definition in the docs, it seems like you're trying to remove unwanted characters in the middle of the string, but `trim()` removes them only at the start and at the end of the string [MongoDocs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/trim/#behavior)

I would suggest you to define a custom `setter`[middleware](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#schematype-options) or `preSave`[middleware docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre) hook for this and transform string using regex (if you want to remove only spaces): `str.replace( /\s\s+/g, ' ' )`